# hook_alter_form() to change an exposed filter

Tags: 7, views

I need to add an exposed filter to my view in form of a select. I followed these steps.

1. I exposed the *Content: Countries (field_countries)* filter to visitors
2. I chose *Grouped filters*
3. I added  *France* with value equal to *FR*

I have many values to add in my list, but I have to select them from my database according to a specific condition. So my list must be dynamic.

In my module, I implemented `hook_form_alter()`.

```
function projects_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $all_countries = country_get_list();
    // $project_countries = Array ( [0] => FR [1] => IT )
    $new_filter = array('All' => t('All'));
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($project_countries as $key => $value) {
      $new_filter[$i] = $all_countries[$value];
      $i++;
    }
    $form['field_countries_value']['#options'] = $new_filter;
    return $form;
  }
}
```

This returns the list I need, but the search doesn't work anymore.

I also tried the following code.

```
foreach ($project_countries as $key => $value) {
  $new_filter[$key] = $all_countries[$value];
}
//$new_filter=Array('All'=>'All','FR'=>'France', 'IT'=>'ITALI')
```

How can I fix the code?

Thank you

Comment: What' type of field is `field_countries`?

Comment: I created a type of content **project** and it contains this field.. my view is for this type: project

Comment: And what type of field is `field_countries`?

Comment: field_countries is a text

Comment: If field_countries is a text field, then `$form['field_countries_value']['#options']` doesn't have any sense. Or that, or we aren't using the same terminology.

Comment: As side note, there isn't any need to use `$new_filter[$i]`. Simply use `$new_filter[]`.

Comment: $form['field_countries_value']['#options'] at the beginning of the function returns Array ( [All] => - All - [1] => France ) and at the end returns Array ( [All] => All [1] => France [2] => Italie )